# Angular call function whenever (a specific) html attribute changes?

Tags: html, angular

I've created a Button that shows a dropdown list whenever you click it (also closes it when you click it again or anywhere on the page outside the list/button).

My button has a HTML Attribute called "aria-expanded" with a value "true" or false".

Basically a button like this :

```
<button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" > test </button>
```

The attribute value "aria-expanded" gets changed automatically by angular whenever the 'custom'-dropdownlist is visisble or not. My goal is to call a function whenever the attributevalue changes. 
It would be awesome to call the function only when "aria-expanded" changes but it would be also fine if the function gets called when a html attribute changes (doesnt matter which one). 
I've tried (change)="function($event)" but it does not work. 
Is it even possible right now in angular?

Comment: How does Angular change the attribute value without you knowing? Your HTML should be derived from your model, which you have control over, rather than your HTML attributes driving what the code does.

Comment: You seem to have used angular unconventionally (if not wrongly), therefore the complete code of how your  "aria-expanded" property is managed would help a lot. The best would be if had the whole button - dropdown code (html + ts). Also if you tell us what you want to do when the "aria-expanded" property is changed, maybe we can submit a more conventional way of using angular. Good day!